# Tkinter doesnt open when I use PIL after trying to move images with the msvcrt module

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a game in tkinter, as I can't download pygame. I use PIL to display images and I use msvcrt to move the images using arrow keys. I don't get an error, just the window doesn't pop up. If anyone has an answer that would be nice! If any one can find an answer please tell me!

```
from tkinter import *

from msvcrt import *

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

lost = False

xpos = 0

ypos = 0



def ShowMe():
    load = Image.open('dog.png')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

    img = Label(image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=0, y=0)
    return


def ShowEnemy():
    load2 = Image.open('freddygifmenu.gif')
    render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)

    img2 = Label(image=render2)
    img2.image = render2
    img2.place(x=800, y=875)
    return

def movekeys():
    while True:
        key = getch()
    if key == 'w':
        ypos =+ 1
    elif key == 'a':
        ypos =- 1
    elif key == 'd':
        xpos =+ 1
    elif key == 'a':
        xpos =- 1
    return

def move():
    img.place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
    return

root = Tk()


def AllFunc():
    ShowMe()
    ShowEnemy()
    movekeys()
    move()
    return

root.title('Chase Game')
AllFunc()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to run program after commenting `movekeys()` in `AllFunc` function.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `mainloop`. You need to change the last line to this:

```
root.mainloop()
```